# ExtJs 4.1.1 Custom Build for MVC Application - Application doesn't run

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In trying to create a custom build for an application, I followed these steps -
1. Added the following in the index.html header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

My app.js file looks like this -

```
Ext.application({
    name                : 'App',
    requires            : [
        'Ext.*',
        'App.view.Viewport'
    ],
    autoCreateViewport  : true,
    controllers     : [ 'MainController' ]
});
```

Afterwards, I run the following commands

```
sencha create jsb -a http://127.0.0.1/index.html -p app.jsb3
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

Once, the app-all.js file is created, I modify the header to look like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
```

The build seems to be happening correctly. However, the application just refuses to run!

I seem to have tried everything anyone's mentioned about 'custom builds' on the net!

Can anyone help or at least point me in the direction of a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example stated in the Question, I had put the javascript file name as app.js

In my application, it was called myapp.js. When you use a custom name for the javascript file, you need to change the 'manifest' (jsb3) file to reflect the same.

Once this was done, everything worked perfectly.

The most detailed instructions are given in [this post](http://blog.lansdowntech.com/2012/02/creating-an-extjs-production-build-with-sencha-sdk-tools/)